# Setting different colors for tabs in Ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic-framework, sass, tabs, ionic3

I'm developing an app using Ionic 3.

I have tabs at the bottom of my app.

The thing is, I want each tab to have a different color but I was unable to achieve it with my SCSS sheet.
I could only change the color of the entire bar but not select each tab by overriding SCSS variables.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Here's my HTML.

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="0" >

<ion-tab className="fontSizeText" [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Scanner un code" tabIcon="camera"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="productRoot" tabTitle="Produits" tabIcon="basket"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab className="fontSizeText" [root]="informationRoot" tabTitle="Sensibilisation" tabIcon="leaf"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="accountRoot" tabTitle="Mon Compte" tabIcon="build"></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Sincerely,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to give your `ion-tabs` element any identifier, like a class or an id. Then you can access your tabs via CSS like this:

```
ion-tabs.yourClass {
    .tabbar {
        a.tab-button {
            &:nth-child(1) {
                background-color: black;
            }
            &:nth-child(2) {
                background-color: black;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

It is not the prettiest solution, but that is the only way I know, to access the single `Tab` elements.

The problem is, that when you put any `class` on to the `ion-tab` element, it will be added to the `ion-tab` and not the link to it. Ionic creates this toolbar at the top or bottom dynamically.

Comment: Sorry for the lateness, and thanks a lot for your answer. However, it did not solve my issue. I'm learning HTML and CSS on the job so I might be wrong. I've added a 'class="myClass" ' in the ion-tabs and copy-pasted your code in the CSS file but nothing changed (I changed 'yourClass' into 'myClass' of course).

Comment: I'm sorry, now it should work. Colors only work without quotation marks. Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hwdwco?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help my friend. Happy New Year.